# How to instantiate automatically all inner classes

Tags: java, scope, inner-classes

```
public class A{
      private String A1;
      private B b;
 public class B{
      private String B1;
      private C c;
      private D d;
  public class C{
      private String C1;
  }
  public class D{
       private String D1;
 }
}
```

I have the following class structure sometimes many more inner classes, When I am instantiating with a generic class, only the constructor A is called and the object A is instantiated, is there a way to instantiate all objects for all the inner classes with there respective default constructors.

The generic class that I am using is below.

```
public class GenericClass<O> {

        private Class<O> clazz;

        public GenericClass(Class<O> clazz){
                this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        public O get() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
                return (O) clazz.newInstance();
        }
}
```

When i do `clazzO.newInstance()` only, B and C will point to null. Without explicitly worrying about all the inner classes instantiation one by one, can I do it in a single shot?!

**UPDATE**: I have updated the class code, 
Here is the sample XML that I will get with Jackson.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
   <A1>Outer Class A</A1>
   <B>
      <B1>Class B</B1>
      <C>
         <C1>Class C</C1>
      </C>
      <D>
         <D1>Class D</D1>
      </D>
   </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to instantiate all inner classes?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to map it to XML - using Jackson, Sometimes i do not need all the class objects, sometimes I would need all. Based on my requirement I would have to instantiate all the necessary object to form the outer class object A. I am looking for a way to instantiate somehow using default constructor of all the inner classes and planning to `set` only required inner members, I don't want any inner class object to be pointing to null.

Comment: @Ivonet i will ignore that.

Comment: To all who downvoted, I want to know what erroneous functionality it would have if I instantiated all inner class objects, I just asked for a simpler approach, I didn't ask for what @GhostCat suggested, I am asking is there any way to do it in a single shot!! please read the question properly. before voting up or down.

Comment: I think this is a typical [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem situation. You might be better of giving a small but "complete" picture. So show us a bit of xml, and your pojo classes and what you intend to achieve here.

Comment: @raghu I really think you are confusing inner classes with members. As GhostCat mentioned in his answer, a class being an inner class is about scoping, not about owning. So you'd better get rid of the idea of making inner classes for each member of your outer class object, before you enter a world of hurt when it comes to code quality. Regarding your actual intent: do you want to skip some XML elements from being mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting things wrong here. You assume that enclosing a class means that an outer class also owns one object of the inner class. But that isn't necessarily true. Having inner classes is about *scoping*, not about implicitly *owning* instances of inner classes!

It doesn't work that way:

- unless class A **contains** fields of class B or C there is **no need** (or way) to create instances of classes B or C when an instance of A is created
- and the other way round: in order to create an instance of B, you **have** to provide an instance of A. And when you want to create a C object, you **have** to provide an A and a B object.

And it doesn't matter if you are using `new` directly or reflection and `newInstance()`! (of course: it matters in terms of maintainability and runtime performance cost - reflection should only be used when absolutely required to do so)

Given the comment: if you want that *fields* of inner classes are initialized, then you **have** to do that explicitly. Like:

```
 public A() {
   myB = this.new B();
   myC = myB.new C();
```

Comment: Sorry not to mention, yes class A contains fields of the inner class. I have a default constructor in all the inner classes.

Comment: *"It doesn't matter if you are using `new` directly or reflection and `newInstance()`*" — Except, of course, the fact that `newInstance` is a runtime lookup for the specified (no-args) constructor of that class. It uses reflection and is way slower.

Comment: Seems like no easy way!!, when I have to do a lot of those. I agree with ur answer I know that is one way. I will wait for sometime. before that.

Comment: @MCEmperor  That is kinda implicit when talking about reflection, but well, reworded my answer.

Comment: @GhostCat It is indeed, but considering the OP is relatively new on the subject, it is always good to make it explicit. ;-)